# Append image and a table in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First I need to append a image in a div then I need to append a table using jquery. I used the bellow code. But it gives an error.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Item Details"></div>

var imgUrl = 'images/aaa.jpg';
$("#dialog-form").append('<img id="theImg" src="' + imgUrl + '" />');

$('#dialog-form').prepend('<table></table>');
var table = $('#dialog-form').children();
table.append("<tr><td>Name:</td><td>K.Senthuran</td></tr>");
table.append("<tr><td>Age:</td><td>30</td></tr>");
```

Please anybody help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: there is no error... even though it can be improved http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/59jYp/1/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/59jYp/2/

Comment: But The browser does not render it. It gives an error. It works fine with chrome. Problem with IE.

Comment: then you need to say what is the error

Comment: Are you realising that you are adding the rows **both** to the table and the image in the div? The `children()` function will return all the children of the div, which, at least, are the table and the img element. Then, the `append` method will add your HTML to all elements in the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to append multiline html code:

```
var imgUrl = 'http://www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png';
$("#dialog-form").append('<img id="theImg" src="' + imgUrl + '" />');

$("#dialog-form").append('<table> \
<tr><td>Name:</td> \
<td>K.Senthuran</td></tr> \
<tr><td>Age:</td><td>30</td></tr> \
</table>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59jYp/4/